# set default value in query in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT  
   Count(*) 
   , Location_tbl.LocName as Location
   , Status_tbl.Status_Name
FROM         
   Transaction_tbl 
LEFT JOIN
   Location_tbl ON Transaction_tbl.Locid = Location_tbl.Locid  
LEFT JOIN 
   Status_tbl ON Transaction_tbl.Status = Status_tbl.Status
WHERE       
   Transaction_tbl.Status='3' and
   Transaction_tbl.Locid IN (5) and 
   DATEDIFF(n, Transaction_tbl.Paydate, GETDATE()) > 10
GROUP BY 
   Location_tbl.LocName, Status_tbl.Status_Name
```

I am getting out put like this:

```
car_count   Location   Status_Name
25          fashion     requested
```

I want to set my `status_Name` always: Violated Request.. how can I do that? In my `status` table not having any status with Violated Request..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just specify a string literal as a column, although I'm not sure why you would want when you can do this from the business logic or display layer instead:

```
SELECT  
   Count(*) 
   , Location_tbl.LocName as Location
   , 'Violated Request' AS Status_Name
FROM         
   Transaction_tbl 
LEFT JOIN
   Location_tbl ON Transaction_tbl.Locid = Location_tbl.Locid  
LEFT JOIN 
   Status_tbl ON Transaction_tbl.Status = Status_tbl.Status
WHERE       
   Transaction_tbl.Status='3' and
   Transaction_tbl.Locid IN (5) and 
   DATEDIFF(n, Transaction_tbl.Paydate, GETDATE()) > 10
GROUP BY 
   Location_tbl.LocName, Status_tbl.Status_Name
```